# How to get Sharepoint Meeting Workspace Lists Items via Web Services?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to retrieve list items related to a SharePoint 2007 Meeting Workspace lists such as Agenda, Objectives, Decisions, etc. using SharePoint Web Services and C#.

I tried unsuccessfully to find out any available method within Lists.asmx or Meetings.asmx web services.

I found some one similar post about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158515/how-do-i-access-the-meeting-decisions-of-a-wss-3-0-meeting-workspace), but unfortunatly without any suggestion.

Thanks,

Comment: I found this [link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/laflour/archive/2009/11/02/sharepoint-2007-meeting-workspace-template-limitations.aspx), it seems that the lists Items depends on the InstanceID stored in a Cookie. I will try to manipulate this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I'v had this same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963864/in-a-meeting-workspace-get-all-agenda-items-from-a-list-programmatically), but i was using Object Model to Query items and luckily the issue was solved. It turns out you have to set MeetingInstanceId parameter either to some specific meeting instance ID, or -1 which will query all meeting data.

For a webservice [Lists.GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method there is the queryOptions parameter you can use to set MeetingInstanceId

```
<QueryOptions>
   <MeetingInstanceID>
      -1
   </MeetingInstanceID>
</QueryOptions>
```

> An integer value where a positive number represents a specific meeting
>   instance. Negative numbers have the following meanings: **-3 =
>   UnSpecified, -2 = AllWithSeries, -1 = AllButSeries, 0 = Series.** This
>   element is optional, and its default value is -1. Negative values
>   correspond to values of the
>   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Meetings.SPMeeting.SpecialInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.meetings.spmeeting.specialinstance%28v=office.12%29.aspx) enumeration.

I haven't used webservices to query meeting workspace, but you can try yourself.